# apprequests popup window css

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, stylesheet

Can you style with css the Requests Dialog of Facebook to your own look and HOW? 
[see Request Dialog Image](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

See "Display mode" section of documentation for [dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/).

Dialog can be show in three modes: page (which is full page on facebook.com), popup (which is really first option but tailored to be opened as popup window) or iframe.

All of the options are out of question, since in `iframe` mode content of dialog is still document on domain owned by Facebook and cannot be styled by anyone except Facebook.

Currently they do not provide any ability to style dialogs (and I believe it's not going to change).

Comment: but i have seen the Requests Dialog without the Facebook style, without borders and on a white background. my question now will be so is there a way where i can display all my facebook friend in a popup window?

Comment: If the question is if it's possible: yes, you can create custom page (which will list all user's friends) and display it in a popup.
Consider asking it as separate question to get more detailed answers

Comment: @VanessaMartinez it's good for everyone if you accept correct answers to your questions, this site community driven, we're here to help each other.

Comment: is there a way where i can display facebook user's friends list in a popup window? and still be able to choose a friend like the Request Dialog.

Comment: like [this one](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/)?

Comment: @VanessaMartinez : As I said before, consider asking this as separate question, there is more than one way to do it and getting detailed answers will help much more. Also it will be good if you mark your questions as answered by accepting one of the answers (you have 4 questions and none of them answered, and badges you have probably not the best one can have). Take your time and learn to ask good questions. You also may want to read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which is really great reading...

Comment: @JuicyScripter +1 for the effort you're putting into this :-) (and for giving the correct answer, of course)